# Using subprocess to execute ADB command

Tags: android, python, call, subprocess, adb

I am sending an SMS using adb. The following command
`./adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:12345 --es sms_body "the body" --ez exit_on_sent true`
, while typed in and executed in bash, does it's job but my python script seems to call `./adb` only:

```
    ADB = './adb'
    def callSMScmd(msg, num):
        adbArgs = ('shell am start -a '
                +'android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:'+str(num)+' --es'
                +'sms_body "'+msg+'" --ez exit_on_sent true')
        call([ADB, adbArgs])
```

The proper return would be `Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SENDTO dat=sms:12345 (has extras) }` Unfortunately this script lists the adb version and all available options; no warnings, no errors.
Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `shell` a separate parameter:

```
call(['adb', 'shell', 'am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO ...'])
```